# Showing functor for composition of morphism two variable functor with one fixed variable?

Tags: category-theory, notation, functors

The following question is taken from "Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative" by Arbib and Manes

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{(1)}$ $\textbf{Definition:}$  A functor $H$ from a category $\textbf{K}$ to a  category $\textbf{L}$ is a function which maps $\text{Obj}\textbf{(K)}\to \text{Obj}\textbf{(L)}:A\mapsto HA,$ and which for each pair $A,B$ of objects $\textbf{K}$ maps $\textbf{K}(A,B)\to \textbf{L}(HA, HB):f\mapsto Hf,$ while satisfying the two conditions:

$$H(\text{id}_A)=\text{id}_{HA}\quad\text{ for every }A\in\text{Obj}\textbf{(K)}$$
$$H(g\cdot f)=Hg\cdot Hf \quad\text{ whenever }g\cdot f\text{ is defined in }\textbf{K}.$$

We say that $H$ is an $\textbf{isomorphism}$ if $A\mapsto HA$ and each $\textbf{K}(A,B)\to \textbf{L}(HA, HB)$ are bijections.

$\textbf{(2)}$ $\textbf{Definition:}$ Given two categories $\textbf{K}$ and $\textbf{L},$ we define their $\textbf{product}$ $\textbf{K}\times \textbf{L}$ to be the category whose objects are ordered pairs $(K,L)$ of objects $K$ from $\textbf{K}$ and $L$ from $\textbf{L},$ and for which morphisms

$$(K,L)\to (K',L')$$

are just pairs $(f,g)$ with $f\in \textbf{K}(K,K')$ and $g\in \textbf{L}(L,L'),$ while

$$\mathrm{id}_{(K,L)}=(\mathrm{id}_K,\mathrm{id}_L)\text{ and }(f',g')\cdot(f,g)=(f'\cdot f,g'\cdot g).$$

To tie all these concepts together we note the following:

$\textbf{(3)}\textbf{ Observation:}$  The map which assigns to each pair of objects $K,K'$ in the category $\textbf{K}$ the set $\textbf{K}(K,K')$ of morphisms from $K$ to $K'$ becomes a functor

$$\mathrm{hom}:\textbf{K}^\mathrm{op}\times \textbf{K}\to \textbf{Set}:(K,K')\mapsto \textbf{K}(K,K')$$

when we make the morphism assignment

$$(f:K_1 --<{K_1}^{'}, g:K_2\to {K_2}^{'})\mapsto \textbf{K}(K_1,K_2)\xrightarrow{g\cdot(-)\cdot f}\textbf{K}({K_1}^{'},{K_2}^{'}).$$

($\textbf{hom}$ is sometimes referred to as the $\textbf{external representation functor,}$ and is often written $\textbf{K}(\cdot,\cdot).$)

$\textbf{(4) Exercise:}$  If $H:\textbf{K}\times \textbf{L}\to \textbf{N}$ is a functor of two variables and if $K\in \textbf{K}$ is a fixed object, then show that $H(K,-):\textbf{L}\to \textbf{N}$ defined by $H(K,-)(L)=H(K,L), H(K,-)(f:L\to L')=H(\text{id}_K,f)$ is a functor $\textbf{L}\to \textbf{N}$ of (one variable).

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

I have asked about the above exercise [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4767365/a-quick-questions-about-describing-a-two-variables-functor-exercise-from-arbib-a) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4773960/notation-related-question-about-a-two-variable-functor-fixing-one-of-its-variabl).  I posted twice about trying to understand the functor notation used in the exercise.  I understand that $H(K,-)(L)=H(K,L),$ means $(K,-)\xrightarrow{H} (K,L):(K,-)\mapsto H(K,L)$ for defining functor on objects.

As for
$H(K,-)(f:L\to L')=H(\text{id}_K,f)$ is a functor for defining on morphism.  In terms of mapping notation, it translates to $((K,L)\xrightarrow{f}(K,L'))\xrightarrow{H}(H(K,L)\xrightarrow{Hf}H(K,L'))=H(\text{id}_K,L)\xrightarrow{Hf}H(\text{id}_K,L').$  I am not sure if that is the correct interpretation. If so, for the case of defining functor for composition of morphism, would it mean: $H(K,-)(f\circ g:L\to L'\to L'')=H(\mathrm{id}_K,f\circ g)=H(\mathrm{id}_K,f)\cdot H(\mathrm{id}_K, g)?$  Then to show the correctness of this equational identity.

Might it be the following: $H(K,-)(f\circ g:L\to L'\to L'')=[((K,L)\xrightarrow{f}(K,L'))\xrightarrow{H}(H(K,L)\xrightarrow{Hf}H(K,L'))] \cdot [((K,L)\xrightarrow{g}(K,L'))\xrightarrow{H}(H(K,L')\xrightarrow{Hg}H(K,L''))]=[H(\text{id}_K,L)\xrightarrow{Hf}H(\text{id}_K,L')]\cdot [H(\text{id}_K,L')\xrightarrow{Hg}H(\text{id}_K,L'')]=H(\mathrm{id}_K,f)\cdot H(\mathrm{id}_K, g)=H(\mathrm{id}_K,f\circ g).$  I am not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote $H(K,-)$ by $G$. So, $G(X)=H(K,X)$ on objects and $G(f)=H(1,f):G(X)\to G(X')$ for $f:X\to X'$. I interchange "$1$" and "$\mathrm{id}_K$" at my convenience. They represent the same thing.

> $$(K,-)\overset{H}{\longrightarrow}(K,L):(K,-)\mapsto H(K,L)$$

In my opinion, this means nothing. It looks like an attempt to use domain-codomain-mapping notation for a function, e.g. $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:\,x\mapsto x^2$ but $(K,-)$ is neither a 'domain' nor an object of a domain and $H(K,-)=(K,L)$ is (sorry) just nonsense.

The 'mapping notation' you use; it's not correct and it also has great potential to be confusing, I would recommend you avoid using it until you're confident about what goes where.

> $$((K,L)\xrightarrow{f}(K,L'))\xrightarrow{H}(H(K,L)\xrightarrow{Hf}H(K,L'))=H(\text{id}_K,L)\xrightarrow{Hf}H(\text{id}_K,L')$$

$f$ is not supposed to be an arrow $(K,L)\to (K,L')$; in making sense of the functor $G=H(K,-)$ we would only consider arrows in $\mathbf{L}$ not $\mathbf{K}\times\mathbf{L}$, so I'd expect to see $f:L\to L'$. Then we have a bit of an error-carried-forward; I don't want to see $Hf:H(K,L)\to H(K,L')$, I want to see $G(f)=H(1,f):H(K,L)\to H(K,L')$.

Then $H(\mathrm{id}_K,L)$ etc. is just ... meaningless, $\mathrm{id}_K$ is an *arrow* of $\mathbf{K}$ and almost never denotes an object of $\mathbf{K}$, and $L$ is an object not an arrow. $H(\text{arrow},\text{arrow})$ makes sense and $H(\text{object},\text{object})$ makes sense - $H(\text{arrow},\text{object})$ does not make sense, sadly.

> Problem: Is $G$ a functor?
>
> Is $G(f\circ g)=G(f)\circ G(g)$ for $L\overset{g}{\to}L'\overset{f}{\to}L''$ in $\mathbf{L}$? In other words, is $H(1,f\circ g)=H(1,f)\circ H(1,g)$?
>
> Also, is $G(\mathrm{id}_L)=\mathrm{id}_{G(L)}$ for all $L$? That is, is $H(\mathrm{id}_K,\mathrm{id}_L)=\mathrm{id}_{H(K,L)}$ for all $L$?

However, your 'proof' for this is problematic because it is using the erroneous/confusing/meaningless 'mapping notation'.

So, how *do* we show $H(1,f\circ g)=H(1,f)\circ H(1,g)$? Here's my hint: try to use the fact $H$ **itself is a functor** - the right hand side is a composition of type $H(\text{arrow})\circ H(\text{arrow})$, so you should be able to use (one of) the defining feature(s) of a functor to resolve this expression.

Comment: From what you have written, here is what I think about how to show the composition: 
From your definition: $G(L)=H(K,L), G(L')=H(K,L')$ on objects, and maps, $G(f)=H(1,f):G(L)\to G(L')$ for $f:L\to L',$  $G(f)=H(K,L)\to H(K,L').$
Also
$G(L')=H(K,L'), G(L'')=H(K,L'')$ on objects and $G(g)=H(1,g):G(L')\to G(L'')$ for $f:L'\to L'',$ $G(g)=H(K,L')\to H(K,L'').$

then 

$G(f\circ g)=G(L)\to G(L')\to G(L'')$

and $H(1,f\circ g):H(K,L)\to H(K,L')\to H(K,L'')$ and $G(f\circ g)=H(1,f\circ g).$

But $G(f\circ g)=G(L)\to G(L')\to G(L'')=(G(L)\to G(L'))\circ (G(L')\to G(L''))=G(f)\circ G(g)...$

Comment: So $H(1,f\circ g)=H(1,L)\to H(1,L')\to H(1,L'')=((H(1,L))\to H(1,L'))\circ (H(1,L')\to H(1,L'')=H(1,f)\circ H(1,g),$ Hence $G(f\circ g)=H(1,g\circ g)=H(1,f)\circ H(1,g)=G(f)\circ G(g).$

Comment: can you please let me know if my solution is correct.  Thank you.

Comment: @Seth No, it’s not correct. You’re fooling yourself with this mapping notation, really. There was no real content, that was mostly a wall of notation. And again the mapping notation isn’t always used correctly eg you make the same mistake with $H(1,L)$ - this symbol doesn’t make sense. Your mapping notation implicitly assumes $G$ is a functor already so it can’t help you. Your solution also never used the fact we define $G(f)=H(1,f)$ as opposed to $G(f)=H(x,f)$ for some arbitrary arrow $x:K\to K$ (and in this case… $G$ is **not necessarily** a functor).

Comment: So please, come back to what I said at the end!! Use my hint in the last paragraph. You do *not* need to draw any diagrams; please avoid the mapping notation for this exercise. Just focus on figuring out why $H(1,fg)=H(1,f)H(1,g)$. To elaborate: your solution isn’t correct because, paraphrased, it just says: “$G$ is a functor because it is a functor. $G(fg)=G(f)G(g)$ is true because it is true (when you draw a diagram)” but you never proved anything.

Comment: I am going by what you said.  how have I not proved it?

Comment: @Seth You aren’t going by what I said, though. You seem to be ignoring my comments; the only change I can see is the use of the letter $G$, which I just used to clarify my post - it’s not necessary either way.

Comment: to show the compositional property for H as a functor, since by what is given: $H(K,-)(f:L\to L')=H(\text{id}_K,f),$ and $H(K,-)(g:L'\to L'')=H(\text{id}_K,g),$ then $H(K,-)(f\circ g:L\to L'\to L'')=H(\text{id}_K,f)\circ H(\text{id}_K,g).$ Is this what you meant by showing?  I am not sure what else to do beyond this.

Comment: @Seth That is not a proof. You still haven’t given me a reason why $H(1,f)H(1,g)=H(1,fg)$ is actually true. I **really strongly** encourage you to do this without drawing $\to$ arrows etc. because I’m confident the notation is misleading you. I’ve said this a few times now, please. Why is $H(K,-)(fg:L\to L’’)=H(K,-)(f)\circ H(K,-)(g)$? There is no direct implication there! You have to do some (very straightforward!) work. Please reread the last paragraph (or the entirety) of my answer.

Comment: I thought the problems was to figure out what the correct equation $H(K,−)(fg:L' \to L′′)=H(K,−)(f)\circ H(K,−)(g)$
 is suppose to be from what is given in the question. I thought that amounts to a proof. I don't actually know how to show it since I don't know how to go from $f\circ g:L'' \to L′\to L′′$ to $(f:L\to L′)\circ (g:L′\to L′′)$
 for the case of the functor $H(K,-).$  I am thinking how about making the use of the following:....

Comment: ....$(1_K\circ 1_K, f\circ g)=(1_K,f)\circ (1_K,g).$ Then $H(K,-)(f\circ g)=H(K, f\circ g)=H(1_K\circ 1_K, f\circ g)=H((1_K,f)\circ (1_K,g)),$. But I don't know how to make it equal to $H(1_K,f)\circ H(1_K,g).$ Also I know the question have to do with something call a bifunctor or right associated functor. Also the concept of natural transformation comes after the chapter session this question is from.

Comment: @Seth Yes! $(1_K,f\circ g)=(1_K\circ 1_K,f\circ g)=(1_K,f)\circ(1_K,g)$ in $\mathbf{K}\times\mathbf{L}$, this is exactly the observation you're supposed to make. **Remember all you need to do for this exercise is show**: $$H(1_K,fg)=H(1_K,f)\circ H(1_K,g)$$And: $$H(1_K,1_L)=1_{H(K,L)}$$For the first part, if $(1_K,fg)=(1_K,f)\circ(1_K,g)$ then $H(1_K,fg)=H((1_K,f)\circ(1_K,g))$. As I said already, **H is a functor**. It doesn't matter if you're not fully comfortable with the idea of bifunctor; the equation $H((1_K,f)\circ(1_K,g))=H(1_K,f)\circ H(1_K,g)$ holds because $H$ is a functor.

Comment: $\mathbf{K}\times\mathbf{L}$ is just a category; $(1_K,f)$ and $(1_K,g)$ are just arrows in that category; since $H$ is a functor it preserves composition. So you're done; $H(1_K,f\circ g)=H((1_K,f)\circ(1_K,g))=H(1_K,f)\circ H(1_K,g)$ as required. I really hope you can see how this is actually a proof whereas what you were doing before (as I commented under another post) is just pushing symbols around without giving any reasons why things are true.

Comment: I edited my post to added $\textbf{(3)}$ $\textbf{Definition:}$ and $\textbf{(3)}$ $\textbf{ Observation}$ sections.  In the second of my linked post, I pointed out I was confused by the definition from (2) because I am not sure if I am suppose to use the product multiplication property $(f',g')\cdot(f,g)=(f'\cdot f,g'\cdot g)$ or $(f:K_1 --<{K_1}^{'}, g:K_2\to {K_2}^{'})\mapsto \textbf{K}(K_1,K_2)\xrightarrow{g\cdot(-)\cdot f}\textbf{K}({K_1}^{'},{K_2}^{'}).$....

Comment: ...but modify it with $(K_1 \xrightarrow{f}{K_1}^{'}, g:K_2\xrightarrow{g} {K_2}^{'})$ instead of $(f:K_1 --<{K_1}^{'}, g:K_2\to {K_2}^{'}),$ in the domain. I don't know how both are related to the notion of bifunctor.  Hence I was really confused about what I am supposed to do.  I am still confused about the difference between product functor in (2) (Definition,) "external representation functor" in (3) (Observation) and that of a bifunctor.  I mean the notations are very very similar.

Comment: @Seth you can use `\leftarrow` to do $\leftarrow$ instead of this $--<$ thing. The hom functor is a very important example but it is entirely irrelevant for this exercise. Have you understood my most recent comments?

Comment: I understand your recent comment.  but I am still confused by all these similar looking notations.  External representation of a functor, product functor and bifunctor, how are they different or similar?

Comment: @Seth Please, one thing at a time. Relax; bifunctors are just functors. You know how functors work. Bifunctors are functors defined on a product category. **All this exercise required was for you to apply the definition of a functor to $H$** and the definition of composition in $\mathbf{K}\times\mathbf{L}$. Product functor is a bit ambiguous, not sure what you mean. "External representation" - I've never heard it called that; the *hom functor* is ... just a functor. It's not a complicated new notion. It's also an important example of a bifunctor.

Comment: ah kk. thank you for the clarification.  The book often don't make things clear about some of the definitions because the way it assigns terms for various definitions, I am not sure at the time of writing, those terms have been standardized in the category theory literature.  It is causing me a lot of confusion for me at times as you can probably can tell during our past interactions.  Like "external representation of a functor" is what a representable functor is, but Arbib and Mane only mentions it by sort of defining it.

Comment: can I trouble you quickly about this $[post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4777447/solution-check-and-question-clarification-request-about-a-question-on-generaliz).$. I just need an explanation for the part in bold.  I am not sure what the question is asking or how to go about it.  Thanks